# Use Color for Rectangle-Stroke

Tags: wpf, resources, styles, staticresource

In a ResourceDictionary I defined a `Color`:

```
<Color x:Key="DefaultButtonBrush">Green</Color>
```

This color I'm using in the same ResourceDictionary for a `ColorAnimation`:

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonRectangle" 
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
    To="{StaticResource DefaultButtonBrush}" Duration="{StaticResource HalfSecond}"/>
```

This just works fine.

Now I want to use the same Color for the Stroke of a Rectangle. There I get the error:

> A object of the type "System.Windows.Media.Color" cannot be applied to
>   a property that expects the type "System.Windows.Media.Brush"

I understand the errormessage, but I don't want to create a separat Resource for the `Brush`. Is there a possibility to use the `Color` also for the `Stroke` of my `Rectangle`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Stroke` is of type `Brush`.You must create `Brush` from `Color` to assign to `Brush`.

```
<Rectangle>
  <Rectangle.Stroke>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource DefaultButtonBrush}"/>
  </Rectangle.Stroke>
</Rectangle>
```